# how to create a List in play framework 2 scala templates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I want to create a List in a template (scala.html).

I have tried

```
val list = @{ List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") }

val list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

@list = @{ List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") }

@list = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

@defining(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")) { list =>
    // code here
}
```

but i always get the error `object List is not a value`. I do not know Scala (i am learning now) but in [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) it has the following example

```
// Make a list via the companion object factory
val days = List("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
```

What i am trying to do is to filter a Map.

I have a Map[Symbol, Any] and i am trying to get all items in which the key is not in the above list. Something like this

```
@f = @{ map.filterKeys(!list.contains(_)) } 
// i do not know if the above statement is correct, because i can't get over there
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just missing an import. I added

```
@import scala.collection.immutable._
```

or just

```
@import scala._
```

in view (scala.html) and worked just fine.

I thought that `scala` package is like `java.lang` package

Answer (score 2):

From it seems like you are doing, it appears that you are writing this code in one of the view files.  Instead of figuring this out in scala, you are better of handling this task in a controller class and then passing that list to the view file.  Doing this kind of work with the '@' notation gets tricky.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use a `Set` instead of a `List`, something like this:

```
@{ map.filterKeys(!Set("a", "b", "c", "d", "e").contains(_)) }
```

Comment: what if he will get `object Set is not a value` then?

Comment: the same with Set i take `object Set is not a value`